# Can the AWS Cognito Id of one Region be used for the Application running at another Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS application running in the Singapore region (it includes EC2, RDS and S3 services).

However the AWS Cognito service is available only in US East (N. Virginia) and EU (Ireland). So I configured Cognito at US East.

Now, can I use the Cognito "Identity Pool Id" of the US East region with the AWS web server in Singapore region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine. The credentials provider will just get credentials to access the web server in Singapore.

[Update from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/amazon-cognito-is-available-in-the-asia-pacific--singapore--region/): Cognito is now available in Singapore region